# Changing tideSDK notification styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, notifications, tidesdk

I am using tidesk to make desktop notifications for my webapp. I am able to use the notification API and am able to generate notifications but is there any way of styling those notifications. I would like to change the notifications css to style it a bit according to my preference. Is there any way of doing that.

thanks!

I dont really have much code, its all pretty basic stuff, but still, here it is.

```
var window1 = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
window1.hide();
window1.setTitle('Application Name');


function showNotify(title, message) {
  var notification = Ti.Notification.createNotification({
    'title': title || 'No Title',
    'message': message || 'No Message',
    'timeout': 15
  });
  notification.setIcon("logo_white_33.png");
  notification.show();
}

function addTrayIcon(){
 tray = Ti.UI.addTray("recycle_bin.png", function(e){
     if (!window1.isVisible())
     {
       window1.show();
     }
 });
}
showNotify("New Reminder", "Reminder for <user> at <time>");
addTrayIcon();
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: After looking at the APIs and searching the net for some good amount of time, I have concluded that it is not possible to style the notifications. So I have decided to proceed with creating my own notifications using the child window concept....yep, it is going to be a lengthier task.